# CSV script upload fails

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, upload

I have a Wordrpess with a custom import script for csv. The file I want to import it has 24 MB and 12000 products. At over 10500 products the script stops.

It worked until I reached this number or products.

Here is my configuration:

```
upload_max_filesize 500 M
post_max_size 500 M
max_execution_time 18000
max_input_time 18000
wait_timeout 60
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Try increasing `memory_limit` as well. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get any imports at all, it means that upload limitations are not to blame. If you were hitting those, none of the import would take place.

The two most probably "candidates" are: execution time was hit or memory limit was reached.

For the former, you already have `max_execution_time` set to quite a large number and I assume your input script is not taking that long. (correct me if I'm wrong)

So the most obvious one is that your script reaches [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) then just halts, hence incomplete import.

If increasing the `memory_limit` doe not help, you will need to enable error reporting in order to find out what's going on.

To do that in WordPress, simply enable [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) by adding the following line in your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

### Optional side note

Having said that, importing large amounts of data by way of unreasonably increasing allowed resources is probably not the right way to go.

Try implementing incremental imports. I.e. the receiving script just parses submitted data, then uses AJAX to do import one by one. Or import submission form takes index parameters (import records 0 to 1000), etc.

Allowing a lot of resources taken by PHP is asking for trouble. Malicious users can exploit that to easily bring your website down.

Comment: You are right about the max_execution_time, the csv is uploading in max 2 hours so is under the limit (18000 s). The memory_limit is 2048. Do you think is not enough?. I have 16 G on server with SSD only for one WP website because of the big amount of resources that takes

Comment: I think that is the move that I have to do, to use different technique, but we don't have time to change it for now. Thank you for your respond.